# Python: String splitting with exceptions to delimiters

Tags: python, regex, split

I'm new to Python, and I'm currently trying to split strings such as the following:

> 910501857403 TBS465   3        TL5     14 W   K      HFP   No         D8-VH

into something that looks like:

> ['910501857403','TBS465','3','TL5','14 W','K','HFP','No','D8-VH']

If I use:

> ln.split(' ')

with a space as the delimiter, I have issues with the ['14 W'] becoming ['14','W'].

Is there a way of overriding the space in this particular instance, using regex for example?

Comment: Please explain the pattern more clearly.

Comment: you could first use a regex to replace something like `14 W` with `14W` then split on `\s`, but we need to know more specifically what spaces need to be ignored - all numbers followed by a single letter?

Comment: No, split (splits on whitespace per default so just use an empty `split()`) on space and then glue back the items witch should be joined,

Comment: There is very little pattern, I am trying to extract a table from a text file so the different items correspond to different columns in the table. The space as a delimiter works well, except for the entries with "number"+" "+"W" or "number"+" "+"V" (this table contains information about electrical data for lighting fixtures)

Comment: Basically any instances where "W" and "V" appear on their own they need to be joined to the previous entry

Comment: This RegEx: `\d+\s?(W|V)` will match any integer of any size followed by an optional space and a W or V. Of course you could just then do two replaces using substring matches.

Comment: Are you sure it's space delimited and not tab delimited? That would make a bit more sense for columns that contain spaces...

Comment: There are multiple spaces between some of the entries, and singular spaces between others... It's a very awkward format!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works:

```
teststring = '910501857403 TBS465 3 TL5 14 W K HFP No D8-VH'
re.findall(r'\w+\b(?! [WV])|\w+\b [WV]', teststring)

['910501857403', 'TBS465', '3', 'TL5', '14 W', 'K', 'HFP', 'No', 'D8', 'VH']
```

How this works: Basically, `\w+\b` matches an alnum character, followed by a word break. The `|` says we are matching either of two patterns. The first pattern uses a **negative lookahead assertion**, to not match if the following characters are a space and either of W or V. The second term matches on a word followed by the W or V.

If your massaging of the input gets too much more complicated though, i agree with the comment, I would just split and post-process.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always elements number 4 and 5 that should not be split, you could simply do:

```
s = "910501857403 TBS465 3 TL5 14 W K HFP No D8-VH"
l = s.split()
l[4] = l[4] + " " + l[5]
l.pop(5)
```

If the assumption is not true one would have to specify the pattern very precisely.

**EDIT**

Based on the comment above, you could first split the string as described above and then use a list comprehension:

```
[x + " " + y if y in ["W","V"] else x for x,y in zip(l[:-1],l[1:]) if x not in ["W","V"]]
```

Comment: or `l[4:6] = [l[4] + " " + l[5]]`

Comment: Thank you, but the format and number of items changes each time, the only indicator is a singular "W" or "V"

Answer (score 0):

To simply  force what you want, I thought why not just concatenate the two strings and then removed the "key" value

```
s = "910501857403 TBS465 3 TL5 14 W K HFP No D8-VH"
l = s.split()
keys = ["W","V"]
for i in range(len(l)-1):
    if l[i] in keys:
        l[i-1] += " " +l[i]
        l.pop(i)
print(l)
```

Output:

['910501857403', 'TBS465', '3', 'TL5', '14 W', 'K', 'HFP', 'No', 'D8-VH']

Comment: little dangerous (popping from a list you are iterating over). it works here... even when you hit the bug (something like `s = '14 V 15 W'`) will skip checking the 15 - but that one will never be a hit anyways in this. Just a note though - you're probably better off just keeping a list of items to delete, and then deleting them after the initial loop.

Comment: Good point, I did not consider if the keys where arranged as you mentioned.